# Rank function in R after group by

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

How to use R to create a rank column? Below is an example
This is what I have:

```
Date       group
12/5/2020    A
12/5/2020    A
11/7/2020    A
11/7/2020    A
11/9/2020    B
11/9/2020    B
10/8/2020    B
```

This is what I want:

```
Date       group   rank
12/5/2020    A      2
12/5/2020    A      2
11/7/2020    A      1
11/7/2020    A      1
11/9/2020    B      2
11/9/2020    B      2
10/8/2020    B      1
```

Comment: Hi Yusha. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you tell us why the ranks are in this order? It's not very clear from your example.

Answer (score 2):

### tidyverse

(I'm using `dplyr` here since I think it is easy to see the steps being done.)

A first approach might be to capitalize on R's `factor` function, which assigns an integer to each distinct value, so that operations on this `factor` is faster (when compared with strings). That is, it takes a (possibly looooong) vector of strings and converts it into a just-as-long vector of integers (much smaller and faster) and a very short vector of strings, where the integers are indices into the small vector of strings. This small vector is called the factor's "levels".

```r
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, group) %>%
  mutate(rank = as.integer(factor(Date))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   Date      group  rank
#   <chr>     <chr> <int>
# 1 12/5/2020 A         2
# 2 12/5/2020 A         2
# 3 11/7/2020 A         1
# 4 11/7/2020 A         1
# 5 11/9/2020 B         2
# 6 11/9/2020 B         2
# 7 10/8/2020 B         1
```

This "sorta" works, but there are two problems:

1. This is reliant on the lexicographic sorting of the `Date` column, for which this data sample is acceptable, but this will fail. A better way is to convert to something more appropriately sortable, such as a `Date` object.

   Failing sorts:

   ```r
   sort(c("12/9/2020", "11/9/2020", "2/9/2020"))
   # [1] "11/9/2020" "12/9/2020" "2/9/2020"
   ```

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rank = as.integer(factor(Date))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   Date       group  rank
#   <date>     <chr> <int>
# 1 2020-12-05 A         2
# 2 2020-12-05 A         2
# 3 2020-11-07 A         1
# 4 2020-11-07 A         1
# 5 2020-11-09 B         2
# 6 2020-11-09 B         2
# 7 2020-10-08 B         1
```

and

2. There really are better functions for ranking, such as `dplyr::dense_rank` (which @akrun put in an answer first ... I was building to it, honestly):

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(Date)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   Date       group  rank
#   <date>     <chr> <int>
# 1 2020-12-05 A         2
# 2 2020-12-05 A         2
# 3 2020-11-07 A         1
# 4 2020-11-07 A         1
# 5 2020-11-09 B         2
# 6 2020-11-09 B         2
# 7 2020-10-08 B         1
```

Comment: My failing was not writing the final answer *first*. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dense_rank` after converting the 'Date' to `Date` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      mutate(rank = dense_rank(mdy(Date)))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
#  Date      group  rank
#  <chr>     <chr> <int>
#1 12/5/2020 A         2
#2 12/5/2020 A         2
#3 11/7/2020 A         1
#4 11/7/2020 A         1
#5 11/9/2020 B         2
#6 11/9/2020 B         2
#7 10/8/2020 B         1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("12/5/2020", "12/5/2020", "11/7/2020", 
"11/7/2020", "11/9/2020", "11/9/2020", "10/8/2020"), group = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Date` column to the actual date object, `arrange` the data by `Date` and use `match` with `unique` to get `rank` column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>%
  arrange(group, Date) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rank = match(Date, unique(Date)))

#  Date       group  rank
#  <date>     <chr> <int>
#1 2020-11-07 A         1
#2 2020-11-07 A         1
#3 2020-12-05 A         2
#4 2020-12-05 A         2
#5 2020-10-08 B         1
#6 2020-11-09 B         2
#7 2020-11-09 B         2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("12/5/2020", "12/5/2020", "11/7/2020", 
"11/7/2020", "11/9/2020", "11/9/2020", "10/8/2020"), group = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```